# Integrating a poisson kernel in $n$ dimensional unit sphere without using that it's the solution of a dirichlet problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Someone has asked exactly this question but the answer was preciselly the thing I cannot use, so I'll ask again:

Let $$K(x,y) = \frac{1}{n \alpha(n)}\frac{1-\|x\|^2}{\|x-y\|^n}$$ be the poisson kernel for the ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$. Here $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the $n$ dimensional ball of radius $1$.

> I'd like to show that
> $$\int_{\partial B_1(0)}K(x,y)dH^{n-1}(y) = 1$$

(here $dH^{n-1}$ is the n-1 dimensional Hausdorff measure)

---

The thing is, **I CANNOT USE** the fact that

$K[f](x) = \int_{\partial B_1(0)}K(x,y)f(y)dH^{n-1}(y)$
is the solution of the Dirichlet problem
$$\left\{\begin{matrix}\Delta u = 0 \; \mbox{ in } B_1(0)\\u = f\; \mbox{ in } \partial B_1(0)\end{matrix}\right.$$

as we used the fact that the integral is $1$ in the first place to prove that $K[f](x)$ is a solution of the Dirichlet problem.

---

On Lawrence Evans' book "partial differential equations" it says simply "A direct calculation, the details which we omit, verifies [...]"
So it should be possible to calculate this integral. I just don't know how.

---

Any tips, or book references that might help me are appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use polar coordinates.

Comment: Maybe useful ... https://www.math.tamu.edu/~phoward/m611/poisson_kernel.pdf

Answer (score 1):

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/724456/poisson-kernel-for-the-half-space-and-ball) there is a very elegant proof of the statement using the strong maximum principle for harmonic functions. Although it uses the fact that
$$ \Delta K[f] (x) = 0,$$
you don't need to use the fact that $\int_{\partial B(0,1)} K(x,y) dy =1$ in first place to show that the Poisson kernel for the ball is harmonic. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but I'll answer it anyway.

Define $k(x,y)=\frac{1-|x|^2}{|x-y|^n}$ which allows us to write

$$u(x)=\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,1)} k(x,y)g(y)\mathrm d^{n-1}y$$

With this in mind let
$$F(x)=\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,1)} k(x,y)\mathrm d^{n-1}y$$
We remark that $F$ has spherical symmetry, that is $F(x)=F(x')$ whenever $|x|=|x'|$. This means that $F$ is equal to its spherical means, i.e

$$F(x)=f(|x|)=\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,|x|)}F(z)\mathrm d^{n-1}z$$

As given in one of the formulas in [my question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4792733/difficulties-verifying-an-initial-condition-evans-pde), which you can easily prove as an exercise, we know that
$$f'(r)=\frac{r}{n}\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int _{\mathbb B(0,r)}\Delta F(x)\mathrm d^{n-1}x$$
However,
$$\Delta F(x)=\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,1)}\Delta_x k(x,y)\mathrm d^{n-1}y$$

But, $\Delta_x k(x,y)=\Delta k(\cdot,y)=0$ and therefore $f'(r)=0$. But $\nabla F(x)=f'(|x|)~\frac{x}{|x|}$
and therefore $\nabla F=0$ hence $F$ is constant. Finally ,
$$F(0)=\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,1)} k(0,y)\mathrm d^{n-1}y=\boldsymbol{-\kern-11.2pt}\int_{\partial\mathbb B(0,1)} 1~ \mathrm d\mu^{n-1}=1.$$

Therefore $F\equiv 1$.

---

**Note:** Verifying $\Delta_x k(x,y)=0$ turns out to be quite difficult, but I might attach this computation later when I get the chance.