# Evaluation of Poisson Kernel in the upper half space ($n$-dimensions)

Tags: integration, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

Let
$$
K(x, y)=\frac{2 x_{n}}{n \alpha(n)} \frac{1}{|x-y|^n}
$$
be the Poisson Kernel, where $x \in \mathbb{R}_{+}^n$ (the upper half-space of in $\mathbb{R}^n$ ), $y \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and $\alpha(n)$ is the volume of the $n$-dimensional unit ball.
How do you show that
$$
\int_{\partial \mathbb{R}_{+}^{n}} K(x, y) \, d y=1 \text{?}
$$

There was an answer provided by [Evaluating the Poisson Kernel in the upper half space in $n$-dimensions](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/60659/evaluating-the-poisson-kernel-in-the-upper-half-space-in-n-dimensions/4152541#4152541)

I just didn't understand why the following step is correct. What is the justification?
\begin{equation}
\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \frac{2 x_{n}}{n \alpha(n)} \frac{1}{|x-y|^n} d y=\frac{2 x_{n}}{n \alpha(n)} \int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-1}} \frac{1}{\left(x_n^2+y_1^2+\ldots+y_{n-1}^2\right)^{\frac{n}{2}}} \, d y
\end{equation}

Comment: If the first n-1 components of x are 0, then it's by Pythagorean theorem. Otherwise, recenter y to make it so the first n-1 components of x are 0.